# mkdir $HOME/ error

Tags: linux, bash

I tried a one line script that worked in one Linux based distro(Linux mint) but doesn't work in another(Fedora). I typed the following line in my bash script.

```
mkdir $HOME/folder123
```

The error i receive:

```
bash: create.sh: No such file or directory
```

I tried creating a folder myself, it gave me a permission denied?

To clear things hopefully: mkdir is in the script create.sh and i run it in the terminal with the command bash create.sh

Comment: what does `echo $HOME` show? is that var in the environment of whatever shell you're running this script in?

Comment: what does `which mkdir` show?

Comment: echo $HOME shows/home/liveuser
which mkdir shows mkdir/bin

I updated my post, not sure what's up with the permission, would that be the problem?(or is this another problem of it's own)? I dont know how to edit the permission.

Comment: try `\mkdir $HOME/folder123`

Comment: `mkdir` should be a binary and not a script, so it should never call any subscript like `create.sh`. Perhaps the command is aliased to something else. Alternatively, and please don't get all upset about it, someone might have been messing with your system, making it look like `mkdir` is still there, but also does some extra things, perhaps in the hopes that you run it as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret your post correctly, you have a file `create.sh` that contains `mkdir $HOME/folder123`, and you're trying to run it by typing `create.sh`.

To execute a script, `chmod +x yourscript.sh` then run it with either `./yourscript.sh` if it's in the current directory, or `/home/whatever/yourdir/yourscript.sh` if it's in another directory.

To make just `yourscript.sh` work, you have to place it in a directory listen in $PATH.

You can do this by copying it to any of the directories listed in `echo $PATH`.

Alternatively, you can create a new directory such as `mkdir /home/you/bin` and then add `export PATH="$PATH:/home/you/bin"` at the end of your `~/.bashrc`. Also make sure `~/.bash_profile` contains the line `source .bashrc`. Then log out and in again.

Comment: that's not how I interpret the question. It looks like when OP types `mkdir` a shellscript is invoked, see comment from @miquel above

Comment: I have mkdir in a script and i run the script in the terminal using bash create.sh

Comment: @user1880760 ok then I suggest you rephrase you question since it wasn't very clear... you might try `bash ./create.sh`

Comment: Is `create.sh` in your current directory?

Comment: You get the error you describe if there is no file called `create.sh` in the current directory. This could be because you uploaded or saved the file to another directory, cd'd to another directory, or named it `creat.sh`, `create.bash` or any other variation.